# Register an app to show in 'complete action using dialog in Android

Tags: android

How can I include my application in this complete action option?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the solution, try the below code:

```
<Activity>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="tel" />
        </intent-filter>
</Activity>


<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
```

Answer (score 1):

These options list all the apps that have an Activity registered to handle to 'call' Intent.  If you want your app to appear, you'll have to create an Activity and register it for that Intent.

To do that you'll need to add a permission in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```

And add this intent filter to your activity in your manifest

```
<intent-filter>
 <action android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_BUTTON" />
 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: I tried this but im not able to get my app in the option when i initiate a call from my phone dialer

Answer (score 0):

To call directly escaping the dialer, try this:

```
Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
call.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
call.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + number));
startActivity(call);
```

Sorry I misunderstood your question. I have not tried it but I hope these two intent filter can help you:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
```

Comment: I have an application , from where i can initaite call.. so when i initiate a call from my phone dialer, its showing options like.. complete the call using... dialer/skypeout.. i need to include my callapplication in that...so that i can complete the action using my app

Comment: i have so many activities in ny manifest, where i have to give this filter

Comment: try to add like this: call.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
  call.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);