# Allow other apps to start my activity when the user touches a download link

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-implicit-intent

There is a feature in ADM (Download Manager) that if the user touches a download link (not a web page), the ADM(Download Manager) will be appeared as an application that has the ability to download files.

What should I do that if the user touched a download link, my application will be appeared a an application that has the ability to download files?

Answer (score 1):

DownloadData class

```
private long DownloadData (Uri uri, View v) {

        long downloadReference;

        // Create request for android download manager
        downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);

        //Setting title of request
        request.setTitle("Data Download");

        //Setting description of request
        request.setDescription("Android Data download using DownloadManager.");

        //Set the local destination for the downloaded file to a path 
        //within the application's external files directory
        if(v.getId() == R.id.DownloadMusic)
          request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(MainActivity.this, 
          Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"AndroidTutorialPoint.mp3");
        else if(v.getId() == R.id.DownloadImage)
          request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(MainActivity.this, 
          Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"AndroidTutorialPoint.jpg");

        //Enqueue download and save into referenceId
        downloadReference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);

        Button DownloadStatus = (Button) findViewById(R.id.DownloadStatus);
        DownloadStatus.setEnabled(true);
        Button CancelDownload = (Button) findViewById(R.id.CancelDownload);
        CancelDownload.setEnabled(true);

        return downloadReference;
    }
```

Description of the above code:

downloadReference: It is a unique id that we will refer for specific download request.

request: Instance of DownloadManager will be created through getSystemService by passing

DOWNLOAD_SERVICE. A new request is generated in the next statement using DownloadManager.Request(uri).

setDestinationInExternalFilesDir: This will be used to save file in external downloads folder.

downloadManager.enqueue(request): Enqueue a new download corresponding to request. The download will start automatically once the download manager is ready to execute it and connectivity is available.

Source :https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1112730/Android-Download-Manager-Tutorial-How-to-Download

Comment: i think you didn't correct understand my question. i just want to know What should I do that if the user touched a download link, my application will be appeared a an application that has the ability to download files? i should write codes in Android manifest. but i dont know what codes.

Comment: Se this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7721905/register-an-app-to-show-in-complete-action-using-dialog-in-android